# TensorFlow: evaluate slice from tensor with negative dimensions

Tags: tensorflow

Using placeholders with an unspecified dimension, how can I slice a vector and print it?

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
for ep in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
    sl = tf.slice(y, [0,0], [1,784])
```

`sess.run(sl)` and `sl.eval()` result in an `InvalidArgumentError` with the message `Shape [-1,784] has negative dimensions`.

Comment: What value are you feeding to the placeholder `x`?

Comment: @mrry : `x` is a batch from mnist. This code comes from the first tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners

Comment: How is `y` defined? I would guess that `y` depends on a placeholder, so you must feed it when you do `sess.run(sl)` or `sl.eval()`.